# How to update a Document in MongoDB when a field is given with karras & clojure?

Tags: mongodb, clojure, functional-programming, mongodb-java, nosql

I have a Collection in MongoDB, I need to update a certain Documents on that, when a field is given in that Document with [karras](https://github.com/wilkes/karras) API {A clojure wrapper to the mongo java driver } in clojure web application?

I've come up with this solution, but, it's not working as I expect.

```
(ns addressbook.repository
  (:use karras.core
    karras.collection
    karras.sugar))

(def test-db (collection (connect) :mydb :user))

(defn no-of-docs []
  (count-docs test-db))


(defn insert-rec [rec]
  (insert test-db rec))

(defn fetch-rec []
  (fetch-all test-db))

(defn filter-db [data]
  (map #(dissoc % :_id) data))

(defn delete-rec [rec]
  (delete test-db (where (eq (str (:name rec)) (str :name)))))
```

*mydb* is the Database in my MongoDB, and *user* is the Collection on which I saves some Documents. I need to delete the Document where *:name* field matches with the rec map's *:name* field which I passed to that *delete-rec* function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(delete test-db (where (eq :name (:name rec))))
```

Comment: Thanks, actually, that is my mistake, but, it should be _eq_ not _gte_. But, it also doesn't work!

Comment: Do you get an error? Are you sure that your where matches anything? Could you post a more complete example where the inserts are also included?

Comment: I don't get any errors, but the Document isn't deleted in the Database Collection. Insert function is there, it works as I expect{insert the _rec_ map in to the database}.

Comment: Try posting a transcript from the REPL where you define the functions, insert some data and then try use the delete-rec function, and test if it works.